# Different environment between server/localhost is changing the date format - php pdo mysql/oci

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, pdo

I'm having problems to configure my server environment, the PHP with PDO is not formatting the date like the localhost.
To test it, I created two connections (using pdo with oci and mysql).
On localhost, oci and mysql runs normally, but on server only the mysql maintains the correct format.

IMPORTANT DETAIL: On sqldeveloper, it shows the data in the same format like localhost pdo/oci.

MY LOCALHOST IS WINDOWS 7 AND MY SERVER IS LINUX DEBIAN X64.

What could to be happening with pdo/oci on server?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
try
{
    $params->host = "172.0.0.0:1521";
    $params->dbname = "geo";
    $params->user = "root";
    $params->pass = "";

    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=//$params->host/$params->dbname;charset=UTF8", "$params->user", "$params->pass");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from tb_geooficio where tipo = 1 and cadastro_im = 37693500 ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

<?php
try
{
    $host = "200.0.0.1";
    $user = "postmaster";
    $pass = "^PostM@ster^";
    $db = "bd_controleinternet";

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db", "$user", "$pass");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from tbl_secretaria where sec_id = 7");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: did you compare the php.ini between environments?

Comment: What I could compare? the timezone on the two php.ini is America/Sao_Paulo

Comment: While I don't know the cause, you can use mysql date functions in the `SELECT` to explicitly specify how your dates will be returned: [mysql date docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use the following to change the default format used for date conversion to match the MySQL default:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

This will make the Oracle dates output like MySQL dates always do.

You can make this happen on every connect with PDO:

```
$driver_options = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'ALTER SESSION...' );
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw, $driver_options);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Both Oracle and MySQL also have functions to format dates explicitly, which you can call in expressions in your query select-list.  But in Oracle the function is TO_CHAR() and in MySQL the function is DATE_FORMAT(), which makes it harder to write RDBMS-independent code.

---

Re your comment:

It seems the NLS_DATE_FORMAT can be set globally in `initORCL.ora`, it can be set by a LOGON trigger, it can be set at the session level, etc.  This could account for the different behavior in two different environments.  Here's an interesting post about it:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:351017764854

Comment: As a $driver_options it's not running. But If try to query it, I get success.

`$conn->query("Alter Session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY'");`

This is really cool. Before I set this as a answer, say me: what you think that could to be happening with the two environments to cause this difference? Big hug.